# How do I arrange my data and plot x-axis correctly?

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib

I have a dataframe that looks like this:

[image]

If I do a simple plot:

`bdp.plot.bar(figsize=(10,6), width=0.85);`

I get this result:

[image]

What's the correct way to create a two-tiered x-Something like this LIKE THIS:

[image]

Comment: Please, put a minimal working example.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming your data frame is named df and you don't require the year to show up,
Try using

```
df = df.reset_index()
df = df.set_index('Flexible working Age')
```

Then drop the year and plot the bar graph normally.
You can do this using a copy of the data frame as well

```
data = df.copy()
```

In case you want to retain the original data frame.

You can label the bars on top with the year if you want the year to be seen.

Use a loop and use

```
plt.annotate()
```

I don't have any of your code so I can't help you anymore.

Comment: That's good, but I do need to conserve the Year data - or at least make it obvious to the viewer which bars belowng to which year.

Comment: I have made changes to the answer, do check it.